# Regex for .Htaccess Redirection

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting, short-url

I built a script to shorten long url. everything works except that when I visit the shortened link I get

error `"Not Found The requested URL /ESrdhPNLMV was not found on this server."`

the shortened url has `http://example.com/ESrdhPNLMV` format. The "ESrdhPNLMV" part is stored as title in the database as the title of the long url.

**Current .htaccess rules**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)\/?\/example.com\/?title=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I got the code from someone and modified with [regex101.com](http://regex101.com) and ended up with above code.
Please what is the correct way to redirect to the stored url in the database when I visit the short link.

**Here is the code for getting url from db:**

```
     if(isset($_GET['title'])){
      //select link from database
  $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM links WHERE title =?");
  $result->bind_param("s",$_GET['title']);
  $result->execute();
  $goto = $result->get_result()->fetch_array();
  $g = $goto[1];
  header("Location: $g"); }
```

**ERROR LOG ON:**

```
$goto = $result->get_result()->fetch_array();
```

**i.e:**

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in
```

read that the above error has a lin to mysqlnd driver, i checked with phpinfo() and found the driver was enabled . so what am i doing wrong here?

**Update:**
Now I have been able to resolve the error message. and going to

```
http://example.com/?title=ESrdhPNLMV
```

now opens the same http://example.com/?title=ESrdhPNLMV

Comment: Does `http://example.com/?title=ESrdhPNLMV` work from a browser?

Comment: No , I get; example.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: Rename your .htaccess and retest this URL

Comment: same thing is happening, been trying several combinations, all no good. does it mean the problem is comming from my code?

Comment: If yo are getting 500 error without .htaccess then you need to check Apache `error.log` to find out the reason.

Comment: 1. PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in                            
 .......................................................................................................                                                                                                                 
 2. PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your rule to this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ /?title=$1 [L,QSA]
```